# Проблемы с методом super()

Tags: java

Всем привет.
Компилятор пишет, что метод super() должен быть первым в конструкторе. Но дело в том, что он и так первый в конструкторе. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так?

```
package com.company;

public class Person {
    static String name;
    static int age;
    void person(String n, int a) {
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }
    void show() {
        System.out.println(name + age);
    }
}


package com.company;

public class Student extends Person {
    String group;
    String speciality;
    void  Student(String n, int a, String g, String s) {
        super(n, a);
        group = g;
        speciality = s;
    }
    void show() {
        System.out.println(Person.name + Person.age + group + speciality);
    }
}


package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person obj1 = new Person();
        obj1.name = "...";
        obj1.age = 0;
        obj1.show();
        Student obj2 = new Student();
        obj2.group = "...";
        obj2.speciality = "...";
        obj2.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: `void  student(String n, int a, String g, String s) { super(n, a);...` это вообще не конструктор и `super` в нём быть не может. И ещё, вы уверены, что хотите вызывать конструктор класса `Object`, вызывая `super` в классе, который наследуется только от `Object`?

Comment: Вы забыли отнаследоваться от Person?

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Person {
  ...
  public Person(String n, int a) {
    ...

public class Student extends Person {
  ...
  public Student(String n, int a, String g, String s) {
    super(n, a);
    ...
```

Comment: Да кажется так же и написал. всё равно тоже самое.

Comment: @АндрійАфонченко Где Вы "так же и написали"?

Comment: Добавил новый код на странице вопроса.

Comment: @АндрійАфонченко Да, я увидел. Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код. Будьте внимательнее.

Answer (score 1):

В классе *Student* у тебя есть метод *student*. Поскольку он - с маленькой буквы, он не является конструктором, а следовательно, в нём не может быть *super*
Более того, метод *super* может быть лишь в конструкторе того класса, который унаследован от другого (при помощи ключевого слова *extends*)

Comment: Давайте не путать людей `:)` Вам никто не запрещает написать `super()` без аргументов в конструкторе класса, даже если он наследуется только от `Object` (без явного указания `extends class`). Это бесполезно, но не запрещено

Answer (score 0):

Разве конструктор имеет возврашаемый тип?
Скорее всего ругается что есть метод с именем конструктора, и переопределение конструктора невозможна изза отсутствии конструктора.

Comment: Конструктор же ничего не возвращает. Там же везде void.